# Can work mandate social activities in South Africa

Tags: socializing, south-africa

Can management force you to partake in social activities in South Africa i.e. can employers make social activities (or part of it) mandatory? Is there any legislation that can assist me and if so can I please be directed to the relevant section?

Please note that the social activity in during work hours for a short duration which employees work back and sponsor. This is also not CSI related.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to add some context on why you don't wish to partake in these activities.

Comment: Can you clarify what "work back and sponsor" means in this context. Does this not happen during work hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to attend a work Christmas party?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120919/do-i-have-to-attend-a-work-christmas-party)

Answer (score 4):

If it's during work hours then the answer is most likely yes - obviously it will depend on the actual wording of your contract and/or employee handbook but there is typically a clause referring to "additional duties as instructed" or similar and that being the case you'd have a hard time arguing to refuse such things. Cases such as *A Mauchie (Pty) Ltd t/a Predcision Tools v NUMSA & others (1995)* show that the Labour court tends to support the notion that the employer can give their employees duties outside of their "standard" job description within reason.